# how to print string inside pyramid python

Tags: python, printing, triangle

I've been given a homework assignment that asks to print an equilateral triangle with '*' as the frame and inside the triangle a string of fixed number of '$' and spaces is supposed to run.

example:
Enter height: 9
Enter number of $: 5
Enter number of spaces: 2

[image]

I am lost here, help?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see over what logic it works. You will find code at last.

#### 1st.

How to create left-side star pattern like this :

```
    *
   *
  *
 *
```

First thing is how many spaces on the left of each star is equal to `TOTAL_HEIGHT_OF_PATTERN - CURRENT_HEIGHT_STATUS`. for given example let's take `2nd-line` so:

```
TOTAL_HEIGHT_OF_PATTERN = 4
CURRENT_HEIGHT_STATUS = 2
NUMBER_OF_SPACE_ON_LEFT = TOTAL_HEIGHT_OF_PATTERN - CURRENT_HEIGHT_STATUS = 2
```

#### 2nd.

How to create `$` and `space` pattern like this in between: (BOTTOM PATTERN IS ONLY FOR VISUALIZATION)

```
        *
       *$*
      *$$$*
     *  $$$*
    *$$$$$  *
   *$$$$$  $$*
  *$$$$$  $  $*
 *$$$    $$$$$$*
```

How many spaces at given height, for above system it is found.
spaces:0  for height @ 1, 2, 3
spaces:1  for height @ 4, 5, 6
spaces:2  for height @ 7, 8

Instead of completely using loop let's divide them in procedural code. For making particular `enclose-string` we can use `make_str function` who logic revolves around the remaining number of `$`

**CODE :**

```
height = int(input('Height : '))
doller = int(input('Dollor : '))
spaces = int(input('Spaces : '))

def make_str(rem, len_str):
    x = 0
    s = ''
    for _ in range(len_str):
        if rem >0:
            s += '$'
            rem -= 1
        else:
            s += ' '
            x += 1
            if x == spaces:
                x = 0
                rem = 5
    return (rem, s)

rem_dollor = doller

for i in range(1,height+1):
    num = 2*(i)-3
    rem_dollor, str_  =  make_str(rem_dollor, num)
    if i == 1:
        print(' '*(height-i) + '*')
    elif i != height and i !=  1:
        print(' '*(height-i) + '*' + str_ + '*')
    else:
        print('*'*(2*height-1))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Height : 9
Dollor : 5
Spaces : 2
        *
       *$*
      *$$$*
     *$  $$*
    *$$$  $$*
   *$$$  $$$$*
  *$  $$$$$  $*
 *$$$$  $$$$$  *
*****************
```